# How can I make SnapKit constrain the left and right edges?

Tags: ios, swift, snapkit

Right now if I want to set the margin equally on the left and right side, it requires two lines:

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.equalTo(Constants.margin)
    make.right.equalTo(-Constants.margin)
}
```

The API also allows me to set all 4 (left/right/top/bottom) edges at once using:

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.edges.equalTo(Constants.margin
}
```

How can I write an extension that will allow something like this?

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.horizontalMargins.equalTo(Constants.margin)
}
```

The result should equate to the first code snippet.

Answer (score 5):

```
label.snp.makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.right.equalToSuperview().inset(Constants.margin)
}
```

Comment: Consider including a short description of your code